# Is there a way to copy via SCP from the switch/router but specify the remote port?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

According to IOS documentation*, you can initialize an SSH session from a switch/router and indicate the remote port to connect to, ex. `ssh -p 22222 1.1.1.1`

SCP, however, doesn't *seem* to have that flexibility. `copy` doesn't allow any connection-specific flags, nor is there an option to add any after entering the `scp` address. This is a bit of an inconvenience when the remote host doesn't use the default SSH port.

I'm 99% certain that this is a "well that's obviously your answer" situation, but it's worth a shot. Are there any "deeper" commands that "unlock" the ability to specify the remote host's SCP/SSH port?

**EDIT**

To help clarify, I'm referring to invoking `scp` *from the switch* to the remote host. So on the switch/router you would be typing `copy scp:remote local` or `copy local scp:remote`

---

<sub>*(Should it matter, I'm mostly using 2960, 3750(X), 3850, 4506/4507, and 6509)</sub>

Comment: I strongly recommend against using non-standard ssh ports, this does not do anything in the way of security and makes your devices vulnerable to other types of attacks. Save yourself some time and change it back to default.

Comment: @brian-winning-jr Unfortunately it's not my server (it belongs to our engineering team) but I agree that changing the ports does nothing to "improve" security. The newest member of the engineering team is pushing to change it back to default so that `scp` will work properly when trying to transfer from IOS CLI

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wasn’t possible to perform from the switch/router

Comment: It should be possible to use SCP from a remote host to transfer files between the switch and whatever host the file needs to go to using:  `scp -3 ${SWITCH_HOSTNAME}:file ${REMOTE_HOST}:file`

Comment: @charles-d-pantoga this would be true if the switch had `ip scp server enable`, but when I asked this question the standard configuration for switches at this place of employment did not enable this. So it was never possible to initiate an SCP session from a remote host. We could only do so from the switch.

Comment: Why are you replying to me 4 years later? Your question was "How do I specify the remote port of an SCP connection", not "How do I specify a remote port for SCP on a machine that doesn't allow SCP connections"... smh

Comment: Because I was closing the question and specifying why your answer was not chosen. Again, as the question states, the user would be on the switch/router to run the SCP command, so Cisco IOS would need to support specifying a remote port, which it does not.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it is possible to specify a remote port. On your the localhost you can use the SSH config. You can also do it like this:

```
$ man scp
    ...
    -P port
         Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that
         this option is written with a capital `P', because -p is
         already reserved for preserving the times and modes of the
         file.
    ...
$ scp -P 6969 /path/to/files.tgz user@remotehost:/path/to/drop/file/at
```

I would suggest using rsync over scp though, and you can specify the port with rsync as well:

```
   rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/DEST
   rsync [OPTION]... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC [DEST]
```

Comment: The question is about SCP on IOS, not some other OS.